# How to trigger a specific element in a list of elements that are created using .map in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm trying to make an accordion, that opens up upon clicking the "+" icon. But when I click on a single element, all the other elements expand. Is there a way to just open one of the accordions? I've added the screenshot of the accordion and also added the code.

```
import { AiFillPlusCircle, AiFillMinusCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import data from "../data";

export default function Container() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

  const clickHandle = () => {
    setDisplay(!display);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="fContainer container">
        <div className="headingContainer">
          <h2 className="mainHeading">Questions And Answers About Login</h2>
        </div>

        <div className="fQuesContainer container">
          {data.map((question) => {
            const { id, title, info } = question;
            return (
              <div className="qCard" key={id}>
                <div className="qCardTitle">
                  <h4 className="qTitle">{title}</h4>
                  <button className="btnContainer" onClick={clickHandle}>
                    {display === false ? (
                      <AiFillPlusCircle size="2.4em" />
                    ) : (
                      <AiFillMinusCircle size="2.4em" />
                    )}
                  </button>
                </div>
                {/* This thing would return the info, or the element */}
                {display === false ? (
                  <></>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <hr className="fHr" />
                    <p className="fInfo">{info}</p>
                  </>
                )}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: This one is for the closed one]

[image: This one is after I click on the + icon.]

Comment: The issue is you are using the same `display` state for all the elements, you need to have an array or an index based `display` state. Which can be mapped to each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

Basically you can't use a single variable to toggle all your elements. All the elements will act as a single element, so either all will open or all will close.

You need something that can be checked against each element. Now `id` is a potential candidate but it has it's drawbacks, since it's a list the best option is using the index of the element itself.

So you first change the `display` type from boolean (`false`) to `integer` type and default it to -1 (anything less than zero)

Then change your `.map` function from `.map((question) =>...` to `.map((question, questionIndex) =>...`, this will get you a variable `questionIndex` which holds the current question's index

You can use that (`questionIndex`) and the `display` variable to check against each other and display the appropriate states.

### Benefits when compared to other answers

1. Since you are dealing with a list of items, it is always best to use the index of an element to toggle the element's display, This ensures you have decoupled your View from your Data. (As much as possible)
2. If for some reason your `id` is null or duplicate, it will create issues in your display.
3. It is easier to just call `toggleElement(2)` to automatically open an element for a given position via code (on first load). This is useful if you want to maintain the open states between url changes / reloads, you just add the index to the query parameter of the url.

### Solution

```
import { AiFillPlusCircle, AiFillMinusCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import data from "../data";

export default function Container() {
  // Update the display to be of type integer and init it with -1
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(-1);

  // Add a parameter to the click function to take the clicked element's index
  const toggleElement = (currentIndex) => {
    // Check if the element that is clicked is already open
    if(currentIndex===display) {
        setDisplay(-1); // If it is already open, close it.
    }
    else {
        setDisplay(currentIndex); // else open the clicked element
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="fContainer container">
        <div className="headingContainer">
          <h2 className="mainHeading">Questions And Answers About Login</h2>
        </div>

        <div className="fQuesContainer container">
          {/* Add a variable questionIndex to the map method to get the index of the current question */}
          {data.map((question, questionIndex) => {
            const { id, title, info } = question;
            return (
              <div className="qCard" key={id}>
                <div className="qCardTitle">
                  <h4 className="qTitle">{title}</h4>
                  {/* Update the button onClick event to pass the current element's index via the questionIndex variable */}
                  <button className="btnContainer" onClick={()=> toggleElement(questionIndex)}>
                    {/* Update the UI state based on the comparison of the display and questionIndex variable  (Note, if they match, you need to open the element, else close) */}
                    {display == questionIndex ? (
                      <AiFillMinusCircle size="2.4em" />
                    ) : (
                      <AiFillPlusCircle size="2.4em" />
                    )}
                  </button>
                </div>
                {/* This thing would return the info, or the element */}
                {/* Update the UI state based on the comparison of the display and questionIndex variable  (Note, if they match, you need to open the element, else close) */}
                {display == questionIndex ? (
                  <>
                    <hr className="fHr" />
                    <p className="fInfo">{info}</p>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <></>
                )}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, It works. I would suggest a small edit, Under the clickhandle function, we could check if the currentindex === display, if it is, then we can use setDisplay(-1), for handling the collapsing of the accordion.

Comment: Good point. Answer is updated. I also changed the name of the handler from `clickHandle` to `toggleElement` to better fit the description of the functionality

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a boolean, use an id in your state

```
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("");
```

When you map an item, add this function

```
  const { id, title, info } = question;
  const handleSetDisplay = () => {
     if(id === display) {
       //Close panel
       setDisplay("")
     } else {
       //open specific panel
       setDisplay(id)
     }
   }
```

Adjust the button's onClick

```
                  <button className="btnContainer" onClick={handleSetDisplay}>
```

Then to compare if your panel should expand, use

```
 {display === id ? ///...: ...}
```

In short, you need to compare the saved ID with the mapped item's id.

If your id is a number, just change the initial state to 0

Comment: It's **not recommended** to use `id` for such UI state changes, one must always try to decouple the UI from the data. It ensures the system does not break on strange/erroneous data entry.

Comment: If a list is intended to not change, then sure. If the list can be changed by adding on removing things, then I cannot agree with this. That is for the same reason that you don't use an index for a key. If you push something to the start of the list, then the index will point to the wrong panel. Also if your id is null or duplicate, then there is some potentially serious problem with the code.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from but given that data is supposed to change, a changing list does not matter as long as all variables change together, which they always should. The over arching point is one must always decouple UI and data, it is dangerous not to and it's very difficult to debug especially when you are in a team with other developers, database admins, etc.

Comment: Can you share any blogs or documentations about this? I would really like to know more about this. I learn something new every now and then that completely changes the way I approach some things, this could be one of them! :)

Comment: Same here, it's always good to read about different perspective. You can search for decoupling UI and it's benefits, its a vast and in-depth topic. There are thousands of articles online.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, @SlothOverlord but I agree with Eagnir. I used to use the ID method in case of removing a specific element from a list, but I wasn't sure how to apply that here. But it seems that Eagnir's method would be more "Conventional" and would be easier to understand while debugging.